# Parsing date and dateTime using regular expression in separate matchers

Tags: regex, string-matching

I need regular expression to parse date and time in separate way in my logic.

I tried use next pattern:

```
^(\d{8})+(?:T((\d{6})[^Z])?).*$
```

My expectation for input data

```
19960404T010000Z
19960404T010000
19960404T
19960404
```

is

```
group1   | group2
-----------------
19960404 | 010000
19960404 | 010000
19960404 | 
19960404 |
```

Can someone check my pattern issue (it does not work as expected)?
To save your time I've prepared [example using regex checker](https://regex101.com/r/QFWK18/2).

Comment: Are you planning on running this regex with a particular tool or language?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I'll run it with java, but correctly parsed result in shared tool is good enough for my case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
^(\d{8})(?:T(?:(\d{6})Z?)?)?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/0ksqwa/2)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(\d{8})` - Group 1: eight digits
- `(?:T(?:(\d{6})Z?)?)?` - an optional sequence of

  - `T` - a `T`
  - `(?:(\d{6})Z?)?` - an optional sequence of

    - `(\d{6})` - Group 2: six digits
    - `Z?` - an optional `Z`
- `$` - end of string

Comment: Thanks, sir. this is exactly I need.

Answer (score 2):

For checking regex you could use page: https://regex101.com

`(\d{8})T?(\d{6})?Z?`

Answer (score 2):

Here is a very generic and simple regex that should do the trick:

```
(\d+)T?(\d*)
```

It captures any numbers up to the first optional T.   Then if there are more numbers afterwards, it gets those too.  Here is a little Python example with the out as requested.

```
thelist = ["19960404T010000Z",
"19960404T010000",
"19960404T",
"19960404",]

for i in thelist:
    thematch = re.search("(\d+)T?(\d*)", i)
    if thematch.group(2):
        print ((thematch.group(1)) + "|" + thematch.group(2))
    else:
        print ((thematch.group(1)) + "|")
```